# Using a suitable Compensator problem - Control Theory

Tags: control, compensation

**Problem:**

\$\,\,\,\$ A system is described by the open loop transfer function $$\frac{k(s+2)(s+7)}{(s+5)(s^2+2s+5)}$$
Design a suitable compensator in order to have \$w_n =\sqrt{10}\,rad/s\$ and \$\eta=0.3162\$

where \$w_{n}\$ is the undamped natural frequency and \$\eta\$ is the damping coefficient.

**My solution:**

From the givens I calculated the required closed loop pole to be $$s = -\eta w_{n} + jw_{n}\sqrt{1-\eta^2} = -1 + j3$$ \$\,\,\$  For this pole, the phase of the open loop transfer function is \$-118.74^\circ\$, so it's not in the root locus. To force the root locus to pass over our pole we need to subtract \$61.26^\circ\$ such that the total phase is \$-180^\circ\$. For that, I used a *lag* *compensator*. \$\theta_z  - \theta_p = -61.26^\circ\$ . I let \$\theta_p = 70^\circ\$ and  \$\theta_z = 8.74^\circ\$   (\$\theta_p\$ chosen randomly). I solved for the positions on the real axis and I got $$G_{compensator} = \frac{0.1922(s+20.5)}{(s+2.1)}$$

**TA's solution:**

This solution used a *Lead* *compensator*. It calculated the phase to be added by the compensator to be \$-62.26 + 360 = 298.7^\circ\$ ,"but the maximum phase that a compensator can add is \$55^\circ\$" (where did that come from by the way?) so it uses 6 cascaded lead compensators, each of which adds a phase of \$49.78^\circ\$. Then it got $$G_{compensator} = (\frac{1.787(s+1.5713)}{(s+5.5)})^6$$

**Question:**

Is my choice of compensator correct? I read somewhere that lag compensators are for adjusting the steady state error but I tried my compensator on matlab and it worked.

Comment: What do you mean by "TA's" solution?

Comment: Teacher's Assistant. Sorry if that was too abstract.

Comment: Just at a glance, your compensator seems fine. You shouldn't need a sixth order compensator for a simple pole placement problem like that. And if it worked in Matlab, I would say you're fine.